# Opening a dateTimePicker using a PictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

Is there any way to open a dateTimePicker using a PictureBox in c# windowsform?
I wanted to minimize the dateTimePicker size so it can only show the drop down arrow and the calendar picture but thats not possible, so now i want to open the calendar using a PictureBox, is that possible?
Thanks

Comment: _open the calendar using a PictureBox_ I don't know what that means.

Comment: Sure?...handle the **Click** event of the PictureBox, then change the Visible Property and/or Size Property of the controls involved...

Comment: @TaW i have a dateTimePicker that i want to trigger when i click on a pictureBox and not the dateTimePicker button itself

Comment: @Idle_Mind do you have the code for that please?

Comment: Code project has a few good examples.  Do a google search for : codeproject c# custome datetime picker

Comment: We have no idea how your form and controls are laid out.  Double click the PictureBox and add some code to the Click() event.  Post what you've got and **SPECIFICS** about your issues then we can help.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is not possible to programatically show picker in DateTimePicker, you can create your own this way:

```cs
[ToolboxItem(true)]
public class CustomDateTimePicker : DateTimePicker
{
    private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
    private const int VK_F4 = 0x73;
    private const int F4_KEYDOWN_LPARAM = 0x003e0001;

    public void ShowPicker()
    {
        Focus();
        var m = Message.Create(Handle, WM_KEYDOWN, new IntPtr(VK_F4), new IntPtr(F4_KEYDOWN_LPARAM));
        WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

Than in `Click` handler of your picture box just call that `ShowPicker` method.

```cs
private void PictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    customDateTimePicker1.ShowPicker();
}
```